Continuous petal count function
Determine the number of times $r=\sin(nθ),~n$ not necessarily an integer, on a polar coordinate system intersects with a circle centered on the origin with radius 1 for all real numbers.
The rose curve is defined for all integers. But at non-integer values, curves that intersect with the circle with radius 1 still exist. How would I model this with a general function, or determine petal count/number of intersections by passing in n?

What is the range of $\theta$? Is it in $[0,2\pi]$ ? @Jack

Try plotting it in Cartesian coordinate (by which I mean, plot $y=\sin(nx)$ for $x\in [0,2\pi]$)

Range of theta is in [0,2π] @Sam

Consider the parametric equaiton of rose curve $x=\sin{nt}\cos{t}$ and $y=\sin{nt}\sin{t}$ for $t\ge 0$. The intersections are equivalent to solutions of $\sin{nt}= \pm 1$, which are given by $$ t = \frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{m\pi}{n}$$ where $m\ge 0$ is any integer. Visually it looks beautiful.

If you truly want to restrict the range to [0,2$\pi$], then the number of intersections is simply given by:  $$f(n) = floor(n/2).$$
However, this is not very interesting.  A much more interesting function would be the number of unique intersections over the range [0,$\infty$).
Then there are four cases to consider:
f(n is odd) = n
f(n is even) = 2n
f(n is a non-integer rational) = more complicated
f(n is irrational) = $\infty$
